# Vaadin 23 configure routes for dynamic and static pages

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I have the following view:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Route(value = "jobs", layout = JobsLayout.class)
@PageTitle("Jobs")
@AnonymousAllowed
public class AllJobsView extends VerticalLayout implements LocaleChangeObserver {
```

with `route = "jobs"`. Such page is available via `/jobs` url

Now, I'd like the following pages:

```
/jobs/{job_id}/{job_name_slug}
```

for example

```
/jobs/123/solutions-architect
```

where I'll show the job description

also:

```
/jobs/123/edit
/jobs/123/apply
```

As you may see, the website may have tons of "dynamic" pages like

```
/jobs/123/solutions-architect
/jobs/4567/program-manager
```

and so on.

And also a few "static" pages like

```
/jobs/123/edit
/jobs/123/apply
```

All of them ("dynamic" and "static") are located under pretty much the same URL pattern.

How to properly configure such routes with Vaadin framework?

Comment: Have you tried https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/routing/additional-guides/route-templates

Comment: Thank you! So based on the url parameters inside the 'setParameter' method, I may create different forms - `If edit - form1, if apply - form2 else - form3` ?

Comment: Also, just noting. When using `@Route` you should not use `@Component` and `@Scope` annotations. Routes will allow autowiring without those.

Comment: thank you! I removed `@Component` and `@Scope`